# How pass object in Redirect in spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created two methods where in the first method I just want to redirect to the new URL with the parameter so I used redirectAttributes but when I use this the object does not get injected and its size is remains 0.

```
    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String AnotherSub(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        RT r = new RT();
        r.setName("Denever")
        r.setLabel("Work")
        r.setId(123)
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("imp", r);
        response = "redirect:/mainTen";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/mainTen")
    public String openMainTenPage( Model model, @ModelAttribute("imp") RT dto){
        model.addAttribute("Name", dto.getName());
        model.addAttribute("Id", dto.getId());
        model.addAttribute("Label", dto.getLabel());
        return "pay";
    }
```

Comment: just return `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `AnotherSub` method to:

```
@GetMapping("/main")
public String AnotherSub(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    RT r = new RT();
    r.setName("Denever")
    r.setLabel("Work")
    r.setId(123)
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("imp", r);
    return "redirect:/mainTen";
}
```